# Improve resolution of concurrent edits

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

When reviewing suggested edits, I frequently end up in a situation where another reviewer has decided to improve an edit at the same time while I did.  There is a JavaScript pop-up warning in this situation, but no real way to reconcile.

Should I simply abandon my edits and start over?

What guarantee do I have that I will not end up in the same situation again in a minute?

Many editors, myself included, make rapid improvements with middle saves -- often not on purpose, but because you notice something you forgot to fix and go back and fix it after saving.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/25239186/revisions) is a recent edit war where apparently both myself and the other guy simply managed to save on top of each others' edits, in spite of the warning.

Because we were editing unrelated parts of the text, it would not seem very hard to apply a trivial merge algorithm in this particular case.

Regardless, it would be extremely beneficial to be able to compare side-by-side what was changed in the competing edit, so you can decide whether or not your changes actually qualify for an override, and/or attempt manual merge of the other guy's changes.

Comment: Actually it looks like my improvements were lost when the suggested edit was approved without changes by other reviewers.  In that scenario, perhaps the entry could be kept out of the review queue for as long as somebody is working on improving an edit.  (I suppose there can still be race conditions, and it could be hard to know when an improvement attempt has been abandoned.)

Comment: This appears to be a cross-site dupe of [We need diff/merge tools for conflicting edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233719). I strongly support the idea, either way.