# Why is there no concurrency control and real-time synchronization for editing questions?

Tags: discussion

I encountered a weird situation today. I saw a question which was really badly structured, so I set out to edit it. I made some edits while, unknown to me, some other user was also editing that question.

Eventually, they posted their suggestions before I could post mine. So when I made my suggestion, it contained many mistakes which I had overlooked and that the other user had already rectified. They naturally felt outraged, blaming me for "sabotaging" their edit and lack of respect for their work as it seemed to them that I had intentionally removed their perfectly good edits. But, in reality, I didn't even know they had already made those edits.

So why is there no concurrency control? Stack Overflow can't bar users from editing simultaneously, obviously, but if someone else already made an edit that was also accepted, shouldn't it reflect on the text that I have in my textbox?
**UPDATE 1**:

(Posted this as answer but new knowledge has made me realize its not the answer)
Following up on this, Today I was editing a post. While I was at it, out of nowhere I received a notification:

> "This post has already been [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33562587/revisions). Your edit can only be saved if it
>   is more thorough than the already revised version"

So I suppose `Stackoverflow` has added that feature to their systems? You can view the revision history presented to me by SO by clicking the hyperlink in quotation.

**UPDATE 2:**
 It happened again. I edited a question and without my knowledge it had been edited before and hence my edit was rejected (Rightfully so).

**Note:** The message statement was not exactly the same as I have provided here but that's the thing it said anyways.

Comment: While downvoting, could you take a moment and explain why you feel that this question should be downvoted? It might save us a lot of trouble and I might take it down instantly.

Comment: In case you're new to meta, downvotes can mean all sorts of things - on feature requests they often simply indicate disagreement with the proposed feature

Comment: @Clive yes this is my first post on meta. I have removed the "feature request" tag from the post and made it just for discussion

Comment: Cool, just don't be surprised if more voting happens that you don't quite understand - it's difficult to get a handle on things with meta posts sometimes. It's quite rare for the general reason for disagreement not to eventually make its way into comments, though, so be patient :)

Comment: With a web based service there is no good way to determine if a user is still working on the edit or just has the edit screen open. If a post is locked and others are prevented from editing it during that time how long should that lock be held for? Also should it also lock out the OP from editing the post to correct errors or add additional information. There are to many problems with it in general. If you jsut lock it while the edit window is active then someone can open the window, walk away from the computer and keep it locked. Or if it times out you have the same problem.

Comment: Note that the whole "agree/disagree" sentiment is intended for feature requests only, but can bleed over into non-feature requests as well.  And then there's the mundane reasons for downvotes like lack of research or poorly formatted posts.  Luckily, reputation never changes due to meta posts (either up or down).

Comment: That's why I said Stackoverflow cant bar users. I don't know about web development but Don't we get notifications saying "there  is a new comment to this question", "there is a new edit in this question, click to reload"? Wouldn't that be helpful in letting people know that they should see what has already been corrected?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290465/3001761, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268366/3001761

Comment: Locking is going too far though. A notification of successful edits might suffice.

Comment: I think one reason not to implement this is: what if I start editing and go out to lunch leaving the browser opened? What would be the minimum time limit to free the post to another editor?  Seems that human handling when there are conflicts is preferred.

Comment: I am not saying that it should lock people out @brasofilo . I already said that SO can't do that. My point is, there should at least be a notification.

Comment: No problem, just bringing more info to the discussion

Comment: Adding a notification that an edit has been done won't always help either as it can be easy to miss if you are working on a longer post and you end up with the same problems.

Comment: I'm the one who accused NSNoob of vandalizing an edit. What made me accuse him was how the timeline of edits was shown to me, it made me believe he did it on purpose. Which wasn't the case, of course. NSNoob was a real gentleman when handling my accusation and explained what happened on his side. // I hope we'll find a solution so that such a situation doesn't happen in the future, it was very confusing for me, and, I have no doubt, for him too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that a warning when you submit an edit while another has already been done sounds great.

I could give an option to see the newest version of the post or even better offer to merge the newly version into your current version.

On the other hand, it rarely ends up with the case you're describing and a few comments between editors are usually enough to solve the problem.
You can roll back to a proper revision and clear up with the other editor you were editing at the same time, there's no reason for normal people to argue about this for hours.

At the end of the day, I think adding complexity to the edit system for the "rare" cases (maybe there's more than I think) isn't worth it.

Comment: Oh we didn't argue at all. He accused me. I explained my case. And he apologized for his mistaken belief. But I see your point how it can be sorted out by a discussion. But it made me feel that there should be something like that, it will only add value to the wonderful thing that SO is.

Comment: @NSNoob What I mean is that the ratio `added complexity / usefulness` would probably be pretty low as thoses edge cases are quickly resolved by discussion.

Comment: @NSNoob And yet features aren't free, the come with costs.  You have to compare the possible benefits of the feature with the possible benefits of the other feature(s) that could be added instead of that feature.

Comment: Of course the complexity will be higher if one had to build this feature from the scratch but this mechanism already exists. What's the harm in using it?

Comment: @NSNoob Thinking about a `git merge` ?

Comment: Not the git merge as it would require extra work on part of SO. (Even though it might be interesting but as you said it is a rare event) They already show notifications for new edits(While viewing question in normal way) and new answers. They could use it to achieve these ends without anything extra to do.

Comment: @NSNoob I've a hard time imagining it, currently fixing a question, someone make a trivial edit, I've the notification: What's next ? Drop my ongoing edition to see the new question ? Allow a reload of the question in my edit box (again loosing what was already done) ? Open a new tab to check (with prayers my browser didn't send me the cached version) ? The notification itself is easy, but handling the workflow after it sounds hard and complex to implement and not worth it compared to how those cases end up actually (fixed after a short talk)